# How to setup Wacom pen button (button 2 = lower button) to scroll

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I have been trying to set up my Wacom pen to scroll pages and function in 3D softwares but after researching the xsetwacom manual and many other posts, it seems that this is a challenging setup to accomplish. Even though it seems to be possible.

After trying some commands in the terminal like:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" Button 2 "pan"
```

and then

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus" "PanScrollThreshold" 200
```

I had no success. I figured out how to use the lower button on the pen while using Firefox only to scroll the page up and down when pressed by going to, in Firefox, settings/browsing/use autoscrolling and check the box.

After reading the xsetwacom manual, it seems that I can setup a "pan" parameter that works only when I have a button or a key pressed which is exactly what I'm looking for however, I'm not sure how to set my pen button 2 to behave like such.

That said, what would be the procedure to setup my wacom pen button 2 to scroll up and down while pressed and behave like a middle mouse button when it is clicked?

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Wacom has their own support and I would think that is a much better place to ask this question. https://support.wacom.com/hc/en-us

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had already researched the Wacom support page but there are not much to look at in there. It looks like there are more useful info regarding this subject on here or stackexchange.

Comment: So the closest solution that I found so far for the posted question is to use the easystroke app available in the repository. Once the app is opened, I added a new action, drew the gesture that I wanted, named the gesture, selected the type to "scroll" and in the details column I selected "Scroll". Now after reproducing the recorded gesture anywhere in Linux, the scroll mode turns on and I can scroll up and down while the RMB on the pen is pressed. Very interesting solution and a good app idea.